# html5 coding redirect not working

Tags: html

I am trying to redirect to another page here and it will not go when I test it both files are in the same folder on my computer

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8/>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=home.html" />

</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to BlazeFirer's Website</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

other page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Blazefirer</title>
</head>

<body>
hello
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your charset meta tag properly, it's missing quotes afterwards.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8/>
```

Should be

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```